Hiding Real Controller Does Not Work
I have a PS4 controller which I want to use for my PC to play a game. Thanks to DS4Windows it generally works, however, for this game, an Xbox Controller is necessary. So, since both (the real PS4 controller and the emulated Xbox controller) controllers are active, there seems to be an issue of the double input controllers which can be solved by using HidHide.
However, in HidHide, I can only hide the emulated Xbox controller which does NOT solve the issue (same issue in the game as with no hiding: the key mapping is totally wrong). When I hide the real controller, it does neither show up anymore in Ds4Windows, nor does it work at all anymore in the game...
What am I doing wrong?
Hiding the emulated controller works:

Hiding the real controller does not:

After reconnecting the device, only the hidden controller shows up:


Is the game your trying to play on Steam. If it is then DS4Windows isn’t necessary since Steam will handle everything provided you enable that support. I use my PlayStation controller on my PC without any additional software other than the game and Steam even games specifically designed for Xbox controllers. The prompts are obviously wrong depending how the game.

Hi @Ramhound, YES, actually it is on Steam (via EA) and the controller is indeed recognized without DS4 Windows. However, the mapping is wrong, no matter whether I activate Steam Input (conversion) or not. It requires an Xbox controller and I have a PS4 controller.

Even EA chat support could not solve the issue... I suspect that the issue is within the game (NFS Unbound), but there must be a way to solve this?

Ah, the solution (from Reddit) worked - although a bit strange. Launch the game from EADesktop.exe via Steam and wait for the controller to plug in until you are exiting the garage - that actually worked!

We don’t have any idea what solution your talking about

This solution worked for me in case of NFS Unbound: https://www.reddit.com/r/needforspeed/comments/z7mw0j/comment/iyk5tpf/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Post a detailed answer.
